# SOLR: does the _text_ field work by default as a catch-all?

Tags: solr

I started working on a SOLR-based search system, and I'm still trying to figure-out what's-what...

I noticed that the `_text_` field works as a "*catch-all*" field, although there is no `copyField` defined to do this.
It simply gathers **everything** (documents content, tags, keywords, etc...).

The only thing I have is this line:

```
    <field name="_text_" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

Is this the standard behaviour ?
**What exactly makes it work as catch-all in this case ?**

Thanks.

Comment: How are you indexing your documents? There is nothing magical about `_text_` as far as I remember, and you should need to explicitly enable the copyField instruction to get this behavior on 8.11 at least: https://github.com/apache/solr/blob/main/solr/server/solr/configsets/_default/conf/managed-schema.xml#L127

Comment: I looked into it more: docs are sent using `org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.ContentStreamUpdateRequest`, to an specific endpoint.  
That endpoint lands in a ` <requestHandler ` defined in the solrconfig.xml file.  
Among other stuff, it has this: `<str name="fmap.content">_text_</str>`  .
Is that it ?

Comment: Yes, that would be it. That maps any unknown fields into `_text_` when indexing rich content through the extracting request handler.